# when i boots up my raspberry pi desktop become black

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, monitor

I try to auto start a python script at startup, then reboot my Raspberry Pi to see if it works.

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

Instead of a normal desktop display, I get a blank screen open box that can only open the menu by right click. So I tried to delete the code I have implemented on start up then reboot again, but the same thing happens. I uninstall open box hoping that it would solve the problem, but I still get the blank screen and the mouse cursor becomes an "X" icon. Has anybody encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem with my Pi and, after checking the link provided by Matt ([lxde wiki](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart)), I found what the problem was and the solution.

I had 2 autostart files:

Global commands:

> /etc/xdg/lxsession//autostart

Local commands:

> ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

And, according to documentation "If both files are present, only the entries in the local file will be executed." 
And my local file was empty.

After deleting the empty file, LXDE desktop was back and no more black screen.

Answer (score 2):

The blank screen open box is the default openbox theme (for lack of a better word). Openbox is required for lxde so you should reinstall that first. To autostart something in LXDE you can create desktop files in your ~/.config/autostart directory (according to the [lxde wiki](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart)) to avoid messing with the autostart file

Try reinstalling openbox and returning the /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart to the way you found it and see what happens. You might have accidentally messed up another autostart command

Comment: what is the next step i re installed open box,then how do i get back to the original desktop display rather than open box blank screen.

Comment: Change the autostart file you messed with back to the last working version and try restarting

Comment: i detect all the files i put in,it only left with the original one.However i still get the blank screen,do u have any solution like type something on LX terminal to recover this.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only file you edited? Could you edit your question and post the file so I can see if anything appears to be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I went into `~/.config/autostart` and found a file named `lxde.desktop` which I edited and commented out (using #) a line that began with something like `OnlyShowIn` or something similar. (After a reboot that line disappeared so I don't remember exactly what It was, It "could" have been NotShowIn but I thought it was something different)

**After a reboot my desktop came back *fine!**

*I had a bunch of `GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1` errors which I cleared up by typing `lxsession-edit` in a terminal window and then unchecking `LXDE` and rebooting

*If you figure out my "OnlyShowIn" confusion - please comment to clear it up for myself and others*

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same behavior, and found the following mistake I made:

I ran:

```
sudo dd bs=1m if=raspbian.img of=/dev/disk2 conv=sync
```

but I accidentally omitted the `r` before `disk2`

I Reran:

```
sudo dd bs=1m if=raspbian.img of=/dev/rdisk2 conv=sync
```

and it booted up properly.

The successful boot on Pi showed a blue square immediately saying "reformatting disk".

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to format the SD card with the ZIP file directly instead of the IMG file found inside after extraction. I got the zip file from the Raspbian download page found here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

With an SD card formatted from the ZIP rather than its contained IMG, my operating system is loading as expected.

---

This solution was applied in Mac OSX using [Apple Pi Baker](https://www.tweaking4all.com/software/macosx-software/macosx-apple-pi-baker/) software and the above linked image.